# iText and org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive not found

Tags: itext, bouncycastle, classnotfound

I'm a newbie on iText. This is my first project using this library.

I'm building a PDF with essentially a big table on it, and while compiling, i'm getting this Class Not Found error: ***class file for org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive not found***

I'm confused, since i'm only using the basic functionalities, and didn't even touch the PDF Signing features. What should i do to fix the error?

I'm using:

- JDK 1.7
- iText 5.3.5
- extrajars 2.2 (which provides bcmail-jdk15-146.jar, bcprov-jdk15-146.jar and bctsp-jdk15-146.jar)

I only using iText inside one class, with these imports:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
import com.itextpdf.text.Chunk;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
import com.itextpdf.text.Rectangle;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
```

If it helps, i would like to clarify that when i run the project inside NetBeans, it compiles and runs just fine. The error appears when i try to compile it to a single executable jar file (which includes the dist/lib)

This is build.xml target where the error appears:

```
<target name="single_jar" depends="jar">

    <property name="store.jar.name" value="Final"/>

    <property name="store.dir" value="store"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <delete dir="${store.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${store.dir}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>

</target>
```

Comment: Current iText versions (e.g. 5.3.5) use BouncyCastle 1.47 but you provide 1.46. Please update dependencies.

Comment: I used the jars provided on the latest extrajars package on the iText project. I'll try 1.47 and post back the results.

Comment: Hi, it worked as you stated. Thank you so much. Please post the answer, so i can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Current iText versions (since 5.3.0) use BouncyCastle 1.47 but you provide 1.46; even though that looks like a small step, there are substantial changes between those BC versions; any sensible version management would have called it 2.0.

Please update dependencies.

Comment: I'd like to note (for others with the same problem) that the extrajars-2.2 package, provided by iText 5.3.5 includes BC version 1.46, which won't work.

Comment: As a side note on dependencies... iText has been mavenized. If you require information on the dependencies, simply inspect its pom.xml. If your project is using maven, too, the correct dependencies automatically are used.

Comment: BTW, currently (i.e. as of iText 5.4.1) BC 1.48 is in use. Thus, always check the BC version required by your iText version.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive` when depending on:

```
    <dependency>                    
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I needed to explicitly include newer bouncycastle artifacts:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.50</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.50</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>                    
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```