# I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive error

Tags: java, pdf, itext, bouncycastle, text-extraction

I want to download and convert pdf files into plain text by using itextpdf.5.4.1. For most of them my code works but for one of them I encountered the error below when I try to read the file.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf_file_path);


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/ASN1Primitive
```

Does it mean that this pdf is protected and there is no way to extract the text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iText and org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042693/itext-and-org-bouncycastle-asn1-asn1primitive-not-found)

Comment: And are you sure you mean [javascript], not [java]?

Comment: thanx @mkl. I editted it.

Comment: please put the appropriate version of bouncycastle in your classpath

Comment: @mkl I have just added extra.jars 2.3 and put the jar file "Bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar". But this time i got the following error. com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package

Comment: *does not match signer information of other classes in the same package* - check whether you have multiple bc versions on your class path. That error might be caused by a mixture of different versions.

Comment: thank you @mkl. I've noticed that I have also pdfbox jar files in the package which cause the error. When removing them problem has been solved.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing the same problem while reading pdf uing itext 5.5.10.

I changed the dependancies to following :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.49</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can also refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27575336/3150912

Comment: 5.5.4 is quite a step back from 5.5.10. Furthermore, this downgrade is unnecessary.

Comment: @mkl i tried this by again going back to 5.5.10 and it works. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That's cause of different versions of itext in your project.
Please, check out your dependencies in your build file.

Comment: If you read the comments to the question, you'd know that it is *not* about different iText versions but instead at first the wrong and later different BouncyCastle versions.

Comment: bouncycasle lib definitely contain above class, but usually it is not being used explicitly. What am I saying is that perhaps this is about dependency from Itext (com.itextpdf or com.lowagie.itext) libs

Comment: and one more thing: target lib could be marked as optional in parent pom.xml (if you'r' using Maven), so sometimes you have to add lib like org.bouncycastle (bcprov) in explicit way into your project.